# Compare two UTF-8 text files and ignore lines that are blank or all whitespace

Tags: perl, encoding, comparison

I am an author maintaining Kindle(HTML) and Open Office versions of a book. I sometimes forget to make changes to one or the other, and the documents are diverging.

My procedure is to copy the text from each and paste into separate text files (using paste and match style in TextEdit) in UTF-8, then perform a differencing operation. However the HTML paste adds blank lines between paragraphs.

I have a file differencing tool, but it has no option to ignore blank lines. My thought was to write a Perl script to remove the blank lines. However, the output of that script screws up the special characters - like ndashes, curly quotes, etc. I have tried using BINMODE and other tricks, to no avail.

I will accept a pointer to a free comparator for MAC OS X that ignores blank lines, or a way to get Perl to not screw up the UTF-8 special characters. I am using Perl 5.14. I prefer answers that do not rely upon newer features, but if I have to install a new Perl, I will.

UPDATE:

This does not work:

```
use open IO  => ":encoding(iso-8859-7)";
open(FILE, "From HTML.txt") or die "$!\n";
open(OUT, ">From HTML - no blank lines.txt") or die "$!\n";
while(<FILE>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;
    print OUT $_;
}
close FILE; close OUT;
```

I also tried calling `binmode(OUT, ":utf8");`

UPDATE: Tried without success this tip from another Stackoverflow question:

```
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "filename");
```

Comment: Have you looked at perl's encoding handling? you can open files as utf8 with `open FILE, '<:utf8', $filename;`. The `Encode` module may also help. Binmode is only useful on systems that differenciate between binary and text files, i.e. Windows. perl v5.14 should have most Unicode-related bugs fixed, so it should work... What code have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you post the whitespace-stripping code you tried so we can get a better picture of why it's inadequate?

Comment: Fair enough. I will post the code that does not work. (My wife rushed me out of the house, or I would have done so earlier.)

Comment: Dunno, I ran the equivalent one-liner `user@computer$ perl -ne 'print $_  unless /^\s*$/;' infile > outfile` and it worked fine … stripping any empty lines from the output.

Comment: I tried that one-liner. It does remove the blank lines, but it screws up accented characters and curly quotes.

Comment: For the future, you might consider putting your book under version control with Git, and then create a pre-commit hook that warns you if you commit without updating both versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the XCode text editor. By selecting a newline and pasting it into the search/replace dialog, I was able to replace all double newlines with single newlines.
Then I saved the file and used my Compare utility.

Answer (score 1):

[GNU diff](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) has [`-B`/`--ignore-blank-lines`](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Blank-Lines.html#Blank-Lines) and [`-b`/`--ignore-space-change`](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/White-Space.html#White-Space).

Answer (score 0):

Err, that "use open" says that your data is *not* UTF-8.  Try binmode on both FILE and OUT?

Comment: Interesting. I will try that. None of the Perl examples I saw applied it to both streams.

Comment: That's because most of the examples will be about changing the encoding; here you want it to stay the same.  Can you show some sample input that it is messing up?  It should write out literally the same bytes it read except for the deleted blank lines.